# Battery status in Android NDK when `/sys/class/power_supply/battery` is not readable

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have an NDK app that reads battery status information from `/sys/class/power_supply/battery`. This works fine on most devices. On some devices that directory is not readable. For example, on the NVIDIA Shield:

```
$ adb shell
shell@shieldtablet:/ $ ls /sys/class/power_supply/battery/
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/: Permission denied
```

Is there an alternate way to obtain battery information in the NDK on these devices?

The Java APIs for getting battery information work as usual, but this is for an NDK app so I would like a C++-only approach.

Comment: perm denied on ls'ing a directory just means the account can't list the directory's contents, but you MAY be able to read the files in it if you know the absolute path/filename leading to them.

Comment: Opening "/sys/class/power_supply/battery/type" from my NDK app fails and I see this output in logcat: `type=1400 audit(0.0:85): avc: denied { search } for name="tegra12-i2c.1" dev="sysfs" ino=366 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_nvi2c:s0 tclass=dir`. The "untrasted_app" bit is interesting. I wonder if it's possible to get my app trusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating a global object in Java with a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcasts. It caches the values and I query them from C++ using JNI. I would love to know a cleaner solution.